# issue facing in recording video and uploading to server in android titanium

Tags: android, video, upload, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I am using Android device for upload video on the server using titanium platform. I am facing following issue when retrieving data.

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE dat=content://com.example.videoupload.tifileprovider/filesystem/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.videoupload/cache/_tmp/tia7257530851591479880.mp4 typ=video/* flg=0x3 }

Following is the code which I am using:-

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera( {
  success: function( event ) {
    // called when media returned from the camera
    if( ( event.mediaType === Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO ) && ( event.media !== null ) ) {

        //  AndroidSelectedImage(event.media.imageAsThumbnail(300));

        var image = event.media;
        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent( {
            action: "android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE",
            //action : Ti.Android.ACTION_PICK,
            //flags : Titanium.Android.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Titanium.Android.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION,
            //data : event.media.getFile().nativePath,
            type: 'video/*',
        } );

        var activity = require( 'main' ).activity;
        //winCertificate.getActivity()
        activity.startActivityForResult( intent, function( param ) {
            Ti.API.info( 'intent :- ' + JSON.stringify( intent ) );
            Ti.API.info( 'intent 1:- ' + JSON.stringify( param ) );

        } );
    } );
} );
```

Help me in this situation. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the code you are using to fire this intent. Also if you are testing it on emulator it sometime give this error due to No camera found or no sd card. As a solution add this in manifest 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> its already added in manifeast

Comment: Why are you using intent  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send you video directly to the server using HttpClient

```
success: function( event ) {
    if( ( event.mediaType === Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO ) && ( event.media !== null ) ) {
        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient( {
            onload: function( e ) {
                alert( 'success' );
            },
            onerror: function( e ) {
                alert( 'error' );
            },
            timeout: 0
        } );
        client.open( "GET", URL );
        client.send( {
            video: media.video
        } );
    }
}
```

With titanium activity start like this

```
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```